# Any evidence for z(h)uang (这么) and luang (那么)?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

I keep hearing:

- zuang [tsuaŋ]

and

- luang [Ĩuaŋ]

for 这么 and 那么, respectively.

I believe it is [Minjiang dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minjiang_dialect) (岷江话, 岷江小片).

I've flipped through a couple of books I have but I haven't been able to find anything to corroborate what I'm hearing.

There is documented evidence for both zang and lang but none for the added [u] sound.

I'd be interested to find anything that documents z(h)uang and/or luang (maybe even nuang) from any dialect or language.

Comment: See the [Wiktionary page on dialectical synonyms of 這麼](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%80%99%E9%BA%BC#Chinese), some of the other words used there may match. Try to check non-Mandarin terms as well, some of them might diffuse across into Mandarin. Unfortunately they don't have a corresponding page for 那麼.

Comment: Where do you hear them? That information might be a helpful piece of context to put into the question.

Comment: @Zuoanqh Minjiang dialect areas.

Comment: It really doesn't have this pronunciation in Mandarin. I think you can read the subtitles first to make sure it is the character, and then listen to the pronunciation of the character in Mandarin. There are usually some similarities between the pronunciation of dialects and Mandarin（Except Wenzhou温州 dialect）。

Answer (score 2):

zuang [tsuaŋ] and luang [Ĩuaŋ] are variants of 这么样（zhe me yang） and 那么样（na me yang---》la me yang）， and the syllables merge into one.